# div alignment using css

Tags: css, html

I am trying to take the div 'widget block' closer to div 'half left' but for some reason the 'half left' div is taking a height.

My code:

```
<div id="featured" class="grid col-940">
    <div id="featured-content" class="grid col-460">half left</div>
    <div id="featured-image" class="grid col-460 fit"><p>half right</p></div>
    <div id="widgets" class="grid-right col-460 ltr-fit">widget block</div>
</div>
```

How can I push div 'widget block' up towards the div 'half left' and cover the gap between two. I can't change the html structure as I need to stick with it.

Full screen -http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/7QE52/3/embedded/result/

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/7QE52/3/

Thanks.

Comment: Did you even make an attempt on the CSS before asking? I don't see any reference to `widgets` in the CSS...

Comment: I tried with creating #widgets and put a float value left there but didn't work.

Comment: Well at least add it to your fiddle so it looks like you at least *tried* something

Comment: Latest is http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/7QE52/3/ . Is it really impossible what I am trying to achieve(That means without using position and changing the html structure).Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know It is not possible without changing the html. But if you do consider changing it, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/7QE52/4/

Comment: Thanks Lokesh.That's what I did in the beginning.But considering the responsive thing I would like to show 'half-left' then half-right and last is widget block and they are all 100% and float none. But I can't achieve this by changing the html structure.

Comment: ...you can use absolute positioning for the widget, overriding any previous code; http://jsfiddle.net/chU8M/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you wanted (I think):

PS: you have to put position:relative to the parent element to position the child element. Also, you have to position the child absolute,if you want the take it out of the flow. Then, you want to move the top down one line. I didn't change your html code at all, only your CSS.

```
    #featured {
      padding-bottom: 0;
      background-color:#dfdfdf;
      position:relative;
    }
    #featured-content {
      background-color:#1A3F70;
    }
    .col-940 {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .grid {
      float: left;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    .col-460 {
      margin-right: 0;
      width: 49.936%;
    }
    #featured-image {
      margin: 0px 0 0;
      background-color:#FC9B32;
    }
    #featured-image p {
      padding:0;
      margin:0px 0px 60px 0px
    }

    .fit {
      margin-left: 0 !important;
      margin-right: 0 !important;
    }
    #widgets {
      float:left;
      top: 20px;
      position:absolute;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. You solution really helped a lot.